# Returning the class which is a foreign key in the database

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql

I want to ask this question and I tried to search for a while without concrete answers.

I have made a database and used LINQ2SQL to auto-generate the classes needed.
I have set the serialization mode to unidirectional to make sure the classes are being serialized and making the datamembers.

Now, what I want to know is, how I can send the references to the other classes (which has been made through LINQ2SQL).

F.x. I have a Class called Scheduler which is referencing Reservation, and Seat, because Reservation and Seat have foreign keys.

You can see the dbml here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mUiO.jpg
The dbml file. This is the model of our database

Also you can see that when I run the WCF test client it does not return the objects of Seats and Reservation.
http://imgur.com/brxNBz7

Hopefully you can all help.

**UPDATE**

Here is the snippet of the code provided by LINQ2SQL.
This is the fields for the scheduler

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Scheduler")]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class Scheduler : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _SchID;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _Date;

    private System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan> _Starttime;

    private System.Nullable<int> _MovieID;

    private System.Nullable<int> _HallID;

    private EntitySet<Seat> _Seats;

    private EntitySet<Reservation> _Reservations;

    private EntityRef<Hall> _Hall;

    private EntityRef<Movie> _Movie;

    private bool serializing;
```

And here is the snippet part of the code where it references to Reservation and Seat:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Scheduler_Seat", Storage="_Seats", ThisKey="SchID", OtherKey="SchedulerID")]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=6, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public EntitySet<Seat> Seats
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.serializing 
                        && (this._Seats.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return this._Seats;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Seats.Assign(value);
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Scheduler_Reservation", Storage="_Reservations", ThisKey="SchID", OtherKey="SchedulerID")]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=7, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public EntitySet<Reservation> Reservations
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.serializing 
                        && (this._Reservations.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return this._Reservations;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Reservations.Assign(value);
        }
    }
```

**Update 2**
Here is the *Reservation* class which LINQ2SQL made:
Here is the fields:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Reservation")]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class Reservation : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _ResID;

    private System.Nullable<int> _CustomerID;

    private System.Nullable<int> _SchedulerID;

    private string _Row;

    private string _Seat;

    private EntityRef<Customer> _Customer;

    private EntityRef<Scheduler> _Scheduler;
```

And here is the *Scheduler* reference part of the class

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Scheduler_Reservation", Storage="_Scheduler", ThisKey="SchedulerID", OtherKey="SchID", IsForeignKey=true, DeleteRule="SET DEFAULT")]
    public Scheduler Scheduler
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Scheduler.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            Scheduler previousValue = this._Scheduler.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._Scheduler.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._Scheduler.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.Reservations.Remove(this);
                }
                this._Scheduler.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.Reservations.Add(this);
                    this._SchedulerID = value.SchID;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._SchedulerID = default(Nullable<int>);
                }
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Scheduler");
            }
        }
    }
```

All of these things should lead to where I could get the object like this:

```
            Scheduler[] schedulers = client.GetAllSchedulers();
            Reservation reservation = schedulers[0].Reservations.First();
```

But get this error due to WCF not sending the object, (which you could see in picture one).
Which is this error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains
>   no elements

**UPDATE 3:**
Ok so it appears that it works somehow.
I just had to make a join between the *Scheduler* and *Reservation*.
Also whenever I debug the code I can see the variables are there. (Due to my reputation I can not post links).

But some of you might recognize the following whenever you try to view a result in debug mode:

> "expanding the results view will enumerate the ienumerable c#"

Whenever I do this, it works, but not if I run it in release mode.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It might be helpful if you posted a snippet of your code here, as well as what it is currently returning.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I have now added the snippets hopefully they will be helpfull :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like only `object` types (`Reservation`,`Seat`)  have `null` values.

I'm guessing either you are missing `DataContract/DataMember` attributes in your complex types or you might need to include [KnownTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx)

It'd be easier to tell if you could provide some code.

**EDIT**

What your are talking about later is deferred loading. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399393%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) blog for more information on deferred vs immediate loading.

When you expand the `IEnumerable` in debug mode, that makes the request to retrieve/load the objects.

What your probably want is to load your `Reservation`,`Seat` objects along with your `Scheduler` object. Something like the following:

```
YourDatabaseContext database = new YourDatabaseContext ())
{
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Scheduler>(sch=> sch.Reservation);
    options.LoadWith<Scheduler>(sch=> sch.Seat);
    database.LoadOptions = options;
}
```

See [DataLoadOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

If you want to understand deferred execution. See [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_linq/article.php/c16935/Understanding-LINQs-Deferred-Execution.htm) article for more details. 
Quote from the article:

> By default LINQ uses deferred query execution. This means when you write a LINQ query it doesn't execute. LINQ queries execute when you 'touch' the query results. This means you can change the underlying collection and run the same query subsequent times in the same scope. Touching the data means accessing the results, for instance in a for loop or by using an aggregate operator like Average or AsParallel on the results.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answering. The problem here might be linq2sql that is autogenerating the classes but will provide the code...

Comment: Ok now I have currectly added the snippets. Hopefully they will be helpfull

Comment: Can you provide code for  `Reservation` class as well?

Comment: Everything looks Ok to me. How do you add the `WCF` service reference?  If you are generating proxy files, check your generated .xsd files have all `Reservation` and `Seat` mapped properly. If not, try generating again. Or you could try using the `Re-use types from assembly option`.

Comment: I add the WCF service reference by the "discover" method. That is to me the usual way. I will try and look more into the options you gave me, and come back again.

Comment: Ah... yeah that makes sense. Also it did help me solving the problem.
Thanks you very much for your help.
Marked your answer.